# how to change display of page if errors in form submission

Tags: javascript, css, django

In my `django` app,I am showing a page that has a `button` which `starts and stops a clock`.The page has a `form` where user can input some details like name,description etc and submit.Initially the `div` containig this form is hidden by `display:none` in the css.Only the button is shown,clicking upon which a clock starts running.When user again presses the same button,the clock stops and the hidden form is made visible .

I did this by using  javascript which gives a status value to the button- 'start' and 'stop'. I have written a function to  if user clicked on it and change the status accordingly.

```
var buttonStatusChange= function(){
    var buttonstatus = $('#clockbtn').attr("value");
    if (buttonstatus == "start"){
        $('#clockbtn').attr("value","stop");
        ...
        hideElement("userinputdiv");
    }else if (buttonstatus == "stop"){
        $('#clockbtn').attr("value","start");
        ...
        showElement("userinputdiv");
    }
};

var showElement=function(elementId){
    var elem_selector='#'+elementId;
    $(elem_selector).show();  
};
var hideElement=function(elementId){
    var elem_selector='#'+elementId;
    $(elem_selector).hide();
};
```

In my django view,I am validating the `userinputform` and other `forms` in the post .If validation fails,the original form is displayed (which now have errors next to the field).

```
def my_view(request,...):
    if request.method=='POST' and otherform.is_valid():
        ...
        userinputform_is_valid = userinputform.is_valid()
        if not userinputform_is_valid:
            return custom_render(request,context,template_name)
        ...
        #otherwise get values from form,save etc..

def custom_render(request,context,template):
   req_context=RequestContext(request,context)
   return render_to_response(template,req_context)
```

html for page

```
....
<div id="userinputdiv">
    ....
    <form ...>
     <p>
  <span id="myfield">Enter WholeNumber:</span>
  {{my_form.myfield}}{{my_form.myfield.errors}}
  </p>
   ...
```

Unfortunately,since the css has a display:none for the userinputdiv, that div is hidden and so user cannot see the errors.What he now sees is a page with just one button which can start/stop clock.If I take the source of the page ,the errors are there in `<ul class="errorlist ...>`

So,I am wondering how to make the userinputform visible to user if any validation errors occur during post.If I make the css for `userinputdiv` `display:block` ,the errors in page will show as expected -but with all the input fields shown , even before any clock is run..and I don't want that to happen,since I am using start and end times from the clock as hidden fields to be sent in the post and processed in my django view

Answer (score 0):

In same situation i'm using Ajax and if get error from server- dynamically add this for fields(i'm write in placeholder).
And with Ajax variant you may run and stop Clock with AjaxStart- AjaxStop function of jquery.